# Why does panda dataframe give a key error on 'Date'?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping

Still new to python. Pardon me for asking a noob equation. Using the mftool library which helps in downloading NAV data for mutual funds. It gives a key Error'Date'.

Would be really grateful on identifying and helping on the error.

Input:

```
from mftool import Mftool
mf = Mftool()
scheme_codes = mf.get_scheme_codes()
scheme_code_list = [x for x in scheme_codes.keys()]
def HistoricalNav(scheme_code_list, start_date, end_date):
    assert (isinstance(scheme_code_list, list) is True), "Argument scheme_code_list should be a list" 
  assert (isinstance(start_date, str) is True), "start_date must be a str in %d-%m-%Y format" # checks whether start date is present and is in correct format.
  assert (isinstance(end_date, str) is True), "end_date must be a str in %d-%m-%Y format" # checks whether end date is present and is in correct format

  main_df = pd.DataFrame() #empty dataframe

  for schemes in scheme_code_list:
    data = mf.get_scheme_historical_nav_for_dates(schemes, start_date, end_date) # requesting NAV data from the api.

    df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']) 
    df['scheme_code'] = pd.Series([data['scheme_code'] for x in range(len(df.index))]) #adding Pandas Series(scheme_code) as a column in Pandas Dataframe.
    df['scheme_name'] = pd.Series([data['scheme_name'] for x in range(len(df.index))]) #adding Pandas Series(scheme_name) as a column in Pandas Dataframe.

    df = df.sort_values(by = 'date') # sorting the values of every Scheme code based on Date

    main_df = main_df.append(df) # appending the data in the main_df dataframe.

  main_df = main_df[['scheme_code', 'scheme_name', 'date', 'nav']] #creating names of dataframe columns 
  main_df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True) 

  return main_df #Returning the required Dataframe.

values_df = HistoricalNav(scheme_code_list = scheme_code_list[0:5], start_date= '01-05-2021', end_date= '01-05-2021')
values_df
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/am364971/Desktop/Python/Working/amfi.py", line 31, in 
> values_df = HistoricalNav(scheme_code_list = scheme_code_list[0:5], start_date= '01-05-2021', end_date= '01-05-2021')
>
> File "C:/Users/am364971/Desktop/Python/Working/amfi.py", line 22, in HistoricalNav
> df = df.sort_values(by = 'date') # sorting the values of every Scheme code based on Date
>
> File "C:\Users\am364971\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5455, in sort_values
> k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)
>
> File "C:\Users\am364971\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1684, in _get_label_or_level_values
> raise KeyError(key)
> KeyError: 'date'

Comment: Can you please put `print("Columns are:", df.columns)` before the error line, run again and observe the output? Is `"date"` there (no spaces, exactly `"date"`)?

Comment: might be a typo in this line:  df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']) should it mean 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['date'])?

Comment: Is it "date" or "data" ? It seems that you do not have the column "date" in your DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that **date** is not a column in the given dataframe. You could check by typing df.columns if there is **date** column.